# handlebars function | helper or?

Tags: handlebars.js

I end up writing this a lot for svg icons sprites.

`<svg class='icon-x'><use xlink:href='#icon-name'></use></svg>`

In Ember, - so / htmlbars / .handlebars --- I expect that I may create a little function like this...

```
var icon = function($name) {
  return "<svg class='icon-x'><use xlink:href='#icon-" + $name + "'></use></svg>"
};
```

and then `{{icon 'twitter'}}` or something.

Is this to be done with a "helper?" or what? `{{#icon}}{{twitter}}{{/icon}}` is almost as bad as just writing the whole thing... if that's how it would end up...

Point me in the right direction so that I can make a little handlebars *something* - to keep the code just that much cleaner.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inline helper sounds perfect for you, the syntax you described being to verbose would be for a block helper which would be really unnecessary.

Ember-CLI (put it in app/helpers/icon-helper)

```js
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(function(value) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString("<svg class='icon-x'><use xlink:href='#icon-" + value + "'></use></svg>")
});
```

Then you should be able to use it like `{{icon-helper 'twitter'}}`

If you are not using Ember CLI, then you probably should look into it, but until then you can register it like this.

```js
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('icon-helper', function(value, options) {
  return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString("<svg class='icon-x'><use xlink:href='#icon-" + value + "'></use></svg>");
});
```

JSBin sample: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vexelodape/1/

Comment: I am using CLI (basically just ember now - right?)

This looks perfect!!!  thank you!!!

Comment: Hmmm... it's telling me that it can't find a helper called 'icon'  .... I guess you are required to have a `-` dash in the helper's name ---  for it to register

I gotta deal with the htmlbars vs handlebars thing though...

Comment: Yes you are completely right about the dash, if I remember correctly it's used to distinguish views from helpers and components or something like that to increase performance (by avoiding looking through all views when a helper is encountered). I'm using this with htmlbars in two projects without any issues, you could probably just drop  `Ember.HTMLBars.makeBoundHelper` instead though to make it Ember 2.0 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I've been able to get it working.

#### i-con.js

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.HTMLBars.makeBoundHelper(function(value) {
  return Ember.String.htmlSafe("<svg class='icon-x'><use xlink:href='#icon-" + value + "'></use></svg>");
});
```

in `app > helpers > i-con.js`